# Page rank using hadoop

Tags: pagerank

I would want to get some experience in using Hadoop and page rank. I am completed a simple implementation of page rank algorithm using Hadoop. Now, I plan to analyse the possible impacts of changing few algorithm parameters and studying how it affects the page rank. For now I am analyzing how the dangling nodes affect the page rank . Any suggestions as to what other variations could be made to this pagerank  would greatly help me  get some deeper knowledge.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of variations as I know:

- Weighted PageRank algorithm: assigns larger rank values to more important (popular) pages instead of dividing the rank value of a page evenly among its outlink pages.
- [Topic-sensitive pagerank](http://www2002.org/presentations/haveliwala-rp17.pdf).

> In the original PageRank algorithm for improving the ranking of search-query results, a single PageRank vector is computed, using the link structure of the Web, to capture the
>   relative importance" ofWeb pages, independent of any particular search query. To yield more accurate search results,
>   we propose computing a set of PageRank vectors, biased using a set of representative topics, to capture more accurately
>   the notion of importance with respect to a particular topic.
>
> Z. Gy¨ongi, H. Garcia-Molina, and J. Pedersen, “[Combating link spam with trustrank](http://www.vldb.org/conf/2004/RS15P3.PDF),”
>
> Also you can try [HITS](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/auth.pdf) (Authoritative Sources in a Hyperlinked Environment).
>
> Going further, you can try to apply the pagerank idea to other domain, like in [TupleRank: Ranking Relational Databases using Random Walks on Extended K-partite Graphs](http://db.cs.duke.edu/papers/2003-WAIM-hxy-tuplerank.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much greeness . that greatly helps